# Keith-wood countdown timer "Days" to "d"

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the [countdown timer](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) as per the title, however, I'd like "Days" to just display "d". Currently I have it displaying `04w 1day 02h 46m` but want it to display `04w 01d 02h 46m`. Can this be done? Thanks!

Current code:

```
var tDay = new Date(2014,10 - 1,20);
        $('#countdown').countdown({padZeroes: true, until: tDay,
            labels:["y","m","w","d","h","m","s"],
            format:'WDHM',
            timezone:+10
        });
```

Comment: 3 libraries totalling many thousands of lines of code for a simple counter? Really?

Comment: :D @RobG using it for many purposes, not just as a countdown clock :)

Comment: Decided to take your advice and write my own function for this particular countdown. Thanks @RobG

Comment: Cool. Often a "general" tool will be quite complicated to account for a whole stack of variables you don't care about, when the actual timer is maybe 10 lines of code. ;-)

Comment: I think building your own counter is definately worth it in this case. But it renders the question a bit useless. Therefor, I've deleted my answer, and you might consider doing the same for the question. Or otherwise you might post the code of your own counter as an answer to provide an alternative to future visitors.